# Are ignite semaphore cleaned up automatically?

Tags: semaphore, distributed-computing, ignite

In our project we are using Ignite semaphore to lock access to resources.
Resources are uniquely identified by UUID and we are using 1 Ignite semaphore per resource.
We don't `close()` the semaphores because it is not obvious to know when a resource is not used. I tried to use `getQueueLength()` and `hasQueueThreads()` to determine if I could `close()` but it doesn't work well.

Obviously the number of these semaphores will keep growing. 
Does ignite remove automatically "old" semaphores (which haven't been updated for a given period of time)?

If not, what would be the better option here to cleanup these "leaking" semaphores

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to `close()` semaphore explicitly to remove it from cache.

Then you can use `removed()` to see if semaphore was already closed and removed.

Comment: Thanks @alamar but how can I be sure that I can close it.
After I acquired the semaphore, after (or before) releasing, how can I know that I can close it (that there is no other node/threads waiting to acquire this semaphore)

Comment: Another linked question, does the expiration policy apply for semaphores ?

Comment: You can have a countdown latch in addition to see if no users are left. I'm not sure that expiration policy can be applied.